# how to filter the some rows by unique id of column while selecting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table. The table has a column. The column has unique id (auto increment).
Totally column has 50 rows. So every row has unique id. For example: the id of column is 1 to 50.

Now I want to filter the rows by column id which is multiple like 1,4, 5,8,12,13,15,17,....
I need query like;
select * from the table where column id !=1,4,5,8,12,13,15,17 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * from table where column_id NOT IN  (1,4,5,8,12,13,15,17...)

Answer (score 0):

=> TRY THIS.

```
$circle_id=$_POST['circle_id'];

 $query = "SELECT * from `mobpostpaid_offer_tbl` ";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
    $parr=explode(',',$row['circle_id']);
     $size = sizeof($parr);
    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) 
    { 
     if($parr[$i]==$circle_id)
}
```